# GitHub actions repository_dispatch event POST request not working due to organisation repository

Tags: github, github-actions, dispatch

I am trying to trigger a GitHub action workflow, which is in my organisations repository and I am the owner of the organsisation

I am trying to trigger using below POST request

curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: token " --request POST --data '{"event_type": "do-something"}' https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/dispatches

But I am getting below message

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event"
}
```

my workflow

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  repository_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '5 12 * * 0'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

I think as it not in my account instead it is in organisation account, that is why it might be giving this error.
Any work-around will be helpful.

Comment: If the repo is under the organisation, should not the URL include ORGANISATION/REPO instead of USER/REPO?

Answer (score 2):

Generate a token from Github Setting Panel with appropriate privileges and use the following URL

```bash
curl -X POST -u <githubusername>:<token> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" "https://api.github.com/repos/<organization>/<repository_name>/dispatches" -d @test.json
```

Where test.json contains your json data.

As per the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event)

This endpoint here requires write access to the repository by providing either:

- Personal access tokens with repo scope. For more information, see "Creating a personal access token for the command line" in the GitHub Help documentation.
- GitHub Apps with both metadata:read and contents:read&write permissions.

Answer (score -1):

`token` - A **repo** scoped GitHub [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).
Validate that your token has full scope of `repo`.

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/dispatches' --request POST \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/javascript' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
--data-raw '{
    "event_type": "do-something",
    "client_payload": { "text": "my custom text here" }
}'
```